# Slice from sections from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given these URLs:

```
/content/etc/en/hotels/couver/offers/residents.html
/content/etc/en/offers/purchase.html
```

I want to remove (slice) from the URL and get only `/offers/residents` and `/offers/purchase`

I wrote this code to do it but I'm getting different results than I require. Please let me know which syntax will work as expected.

```
var test1 = '/content/etc/en/hotels/couver/offers/residents.html'
test1 = test1.slice(0,5);

var test2 = '/content/etc/en/offers/purchase.html'
test2 = test2.slice(0,5);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to split the strings by `/` and then only use the last two sections of the path to rebuild a string:

```js
['/content/etc/en/hotels/couver/offers/residents.html', '/content/etc/en/offers/purchase.html'].forEach(function(url) {
  var locs = url.replace(/\.\w+$/, '').split('/');
  var output = locs.slice(-2).join('/');
  console.log(output);
});
```

Alternatively you could use a regular expression to only retrieve the parts you require:

```js
['/content/etc/en/hotels/couver/offers/residents.html', '/content/etc/en/offers/purchase.html'].forEach(function(url) {
  var locs = url.replace(/.+\/(\w+\/\w+)\.\w+$/, '$1');
  console.log(locs);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the substring that you want with regex. In the example below the matches[1] will contain the wanted substring.

```
var str = '/content/etc/en/hotels/couver/offers/residents.html';
var matches = str.match(/([\w]+\/[\w]+)\.html/);
var parsed = matches[1];
```

Comment: Thanks.. But, i dont need .html .. now its getting "offers/residents.html"

Comment: Edited it not to get the .html

Answer (score 0):

this is what you meant for?
to change the slice numbers?

```js
var test1 = '/content/etc/en/hotels/couver/offers/residents.html'
test1 = test1.slice(29,46);

var test2 = '/content/etc/en/offers/purchase.html'
test2 = test2.slice(15,31);
```

Comment: This solution might be somewhat brittle, as almost *any* change to the path breaks it.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex, to remove everything before and after string, that starts from /offers and ends with .html

```js
const str1 = '/content/etc/en/hotels/couver/offers/residents.html';
const str2 = '/content/etc/en/offers/purchase.html';

const regex = /^(.*)(\/offers\/.*)(.html)$/g;

console.log(str1.replace(regex, '$2')); // /offers/residents

console.log(str2.replace(regex, '$2')); // /offers/purchase
```

https://regex101.com/r/hRwLHi/1